# How to re-render React components without actually changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React application I have a component called `Value`, which has several instances on multiple levels of the DOM tree. Its value can be shown or hidden, and by clicking on it, it shows up or gets hidden (like flipping a card).

I would like to make 2 buttons, "Show all" and "Hide all", which would make all these instances of the `Value` component to show up or get hidden. I created these buttons in a component (called `Cases`) which is a parent of each of the instances of the `Value` component. It has a state called `mode`, and clicking the buttons sets it to "showAll" or "hideAll". I use React Context to provide this chosen mode to the `Value` component.

My problem: after I click the "Hide All" button and then make some `Value` instances visible by clicking on them, I'm not able to hide all of them again. I guess it is because the Value components won't re-render, because even though the `setMode("hideAll")` function is called, it doesn't actually change the value of the state.

Is there a way I can make the `Value` instances re-render after calling the `setMode` function, even though no actual change was made?
I'm relatively new to React and web-development, I'm not sure if it is the right approach, so I'd also be happy to get some advices about what a better solution would be.

Here are the code for my components:

```
const ModeContext = React.createContext()

export default function Cases() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("hideAll") 
  return (
    <>
        <div>
           <button onClick={() => setMode("showAll")}>Show all answers</button>
           <button onClick={() => setMode("hideAll")}>Hide all answers</button>
        </div>
        <ModeContext.Provider value={mode}>
            <div>
                {cases.map( item => <Case key={item.name} {...item}/> ) }
            </div>
        </ModeContext.Provider>   
    </>
  )
}

export default function Value(props) {
  const mode = useContext(ModeContext)
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(mode === "showAll" ? false : true)

  useEffect(() => {
        if (mode === "showAll") setHidden(false)
        else if (mode === "hideAll") setHidden(true)
    }, [mode])

  return (
    hidden 
        ? <span className="hiddenValue" onClick={() => setHidden(!hidden)}></span> 
        : <span className="value" onClick={() => setHidden(!hidden)}>{props.children}</span>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can check whether `Value` component is rendering or not by using React Developer Tools or some logs or ... . Any time a context is updated, any component calling `useContext` will be updated as well. You can also assign an id to each `Value` component and keep a state of visibility of each `Value` in a top level component like `Cases`. This way you have single source of truth and full flexibility. But this may not be the case for you.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create your context before you can use it as a provider or user.

So make sure to add this to the top of the file.

```js
const ModeContext = React.createContext('hideAll')
```

As it stands, since `ModeContext` isn't created, `mode` in your `Value` component should be undefined and never change.

If your components are on separate files, make sure to also export `ModeContext` and import it in the other component.

#### Example

Here's one way to organize everything and keep it simple.

```js
// cases.js

const ModeContext = React.createContext('hideAll')

export default function Cases() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("hideAll") 
  return (
    <>
        <div>
           <button onClick={() => setMode("showAll")}>Show all answers</button>
           <button onClick={() => setMode("hideAll")}>Hide all answers</button>
        </div>
        <ModeContext.Provider value={mode}>
            <div>
                {cases.map( item => <Case key={item.name} {...item}/> ) }
            </div>
        </ModeContext.Provider>   
    </>
  )
}

export function useModeContext() {
  return useContext(ModeContext)
}
```

```js
// value.js

import { useModeContext } from './cases.js'

export default function Value(props) {
  const mode = useContext(ModeContext)
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(mode === "showAll" ? false : true)

  useEffect(() => {
        if (mode === "showAll") setHidden(false)
        else if (mode === "hideAll") setHidden(true)
    }, [mode])

  return (
    hidden 
        ? <span className="hiddenValue" onClick={() => setHidden(!hidden)}></span> 
        : <span className="value" onClick={() => setHidden(!hidden)}>{props.children}</span>
  )
}
```

P.S. I've made this mistake many times, too.

Comment: Thank you, actually I have created it, just didn't copy that line. My mistake, sorry. Now I updated the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a new state in the Value component. Your components should have an [only single of truth][1], in your case is `mode`. In your context, you should provide also a function to hide the components, you can call `setHidden`

Change the Value component like the following:

```
export default function Value(props) {
  const { mode, setHidden } = useContext(ModeContext)
  
  if(mode === "showAll") {
        return <span className="hiddenValue" onClick={() => setHidden("hideAll")}></span> 
        } else if(mode === "hideAll") { 
        return <span className="value" onClick={() => setHidden("showAll")}>{props.children}</span>
} else {
 return null; 
}
  )
}
```

P.S. Because `mode` seems a boolean value, you can switch between true and false.
[1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but couldn't make it work as useContext(ModeContext) returns only a string (hideAll), so destructuring to { mode, setHidden } doesn't work

Comment: You should refractor also modeContext to support the function to hide/show the element

Comment: Could you please give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: From the docs, check [toogleTheme](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component) implementation. You pass down a function which can update the state of mode

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this scenario.

1. Move the state in the parent component. Track all visible states in the parent component like this:

```
  const [visible, setVisibilty] = useState(cases.map(() => true))
...
<button onClick={() => setVisibilty(casses.map(() => false)}>Hide all answers</button>
...
 {cases.map((item, index) => <Case key={item.name} visible={visible[index]} {...item}/> ) }
```

2. Reset the mode after it reset all states:

```
const [mode, setMode] = useState("hideAll") 
useEffect(() => {
   setMode("")
}, [mode])
```